# If tag equals then show else show

Tags: php, tags, conditional-tags

In my WordPress I have a page template called: `single_jobs.php`

In the template is shown a contact formular. Linked in the template file like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="207"]' ); ?>
```

When creating a page on the single.job template it is possible to set a tag. I would like to have the template testing if the tag is on the page, and if it is, it should not  be showing the contact form, but instead just a short sentence.

Is this possibly, and how would I implement it. I am a newbie in PHP, so hoping for detailed answers.

Answer (score 5):

Look at [`has_tag()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_tag). It seems that is what you are looking for

You can use it like follow

```
if( has_tag( 'NAME OF TAG' ) ) {
    // do something if has tag
}else{
    // do something else if not have tag
}
```